# show local users in another users area?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi im new to php and mysql and i was wondering if there was a way that i could display a list of users on my site to other users that are within a certain distance of each others post code? So when users register they register a postcode and this brings up a list of users near them?

so if

- user (a) lived at m3 4jj
- and user (b) lived at m3 4ej

these two would be within 1 mile of each other.

is there a way of doing this in php and mysql? and can someone please show me where to begin with this or share any tutorials. thanks.

would i not be able to create something even more basic in myqsl like (without the need of any additional api or databases?):

```
function get_local_users() {
            global $connection;
            $query = "SELECT *,MATCH(user_postcode) AGAINST ('user_postcode' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance FROM ptb_stats WHERE MATCH(user_postcode) AGAINST('user_postcode' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    AND ptb_users.account_type = \"User\" AND ptb_users.account_status = \"Active\" AND ptb_stats.user_id = ptb_users.id
                        AND ptb_profiles.user_id=ptb_stats.user_id
                        AND ptb_users.profile_hidden='0'
                         ORDER BY relevance DESC LIMIT 5";
            $local_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            confirm_query($local_set);
            return $local_set;
        }
```

Comment: May be google maps provide some think like that, calculate the distance between two given addresses, and return the miles. Then you can decide if a user near to another user by the returned value, `if(calcDistance(addressUser01, addressUser02) < 10miles) echo "User02 near to User01"; //this is just pseudo code`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather broad topic to be asking as a single question, as it touches on an entire application's logic.

I think the key part in this case is not how you would organize the database or write the PHP, but how you would calculate the distance between two postcodes. That requires some kind of service or database which can map post codes to geographic locations; that may mean paying for one, depending on the precision you want.

Edit: In case it's unclear (particularly to non-UK users), the UK's Postcode system is based on *population* (i.e. number of addresses) not on *location*. Consequently, rural Postcodes will cover a much larger area than urban ones, and new postcodes are sometimes "in-filled" as cities grow, leading to somewhat unpredictable boundaries and adjacent codes. A full post code, such as "M3 4JJ" indicates as few as 8 addresses, so with the right database can be mapped very precisely, but by the same token means such databases are very large.

Edit2: It seems I'm out of date on my "might be expensive", as the Ordnance Survey now provides a [free version of their Postcode to map location data](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/products/code-point-open/index.html).

Comment: would it be possible to write a mysql query that uses MATCH function to say if the postcode is an m3 postcode then all other postcodes that begin with m3 are a match and thus to display these matches as users local in their area?

Comment: @JohnSmith It's possible, but it would be very limited and imprecise. For instance, the BN20 postcode area covers a large rural area, but touches parts of Eastbourne, which are therefore much nearer to all of BN21 than the far edge of BN20. To its North, you will approach BN26, and West, BN25. The UK Post Code system really doesn't lend itself to this kind of string-based comparison.